# How to call a colorbox with several items?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I´ve got the following code:

```
<div class="item_1">
<div class="Logo"></div>
<div class="Name"></div>
<div class="Link"></div>
<div class="Inhalt_lightbox">Content 1</div>
</div>
<div class="item_2">
<div class="Logo"></div>
<div class="Name"></div>
<div class="Link"></div>
<div class="Inhalt_lightbox">Content 2</div>
</div>
<div class="item_3">
<div class="Logo"></div>
<div class="Name"></div>
<div class="Link"></div>
<div class="Inhalt_lightbox">Content 3</div>
</div>
```

When I click on the link in "item_1", the content of the div "Inhalt_lightbox" in "item_1" should show up in a light box.
How can i do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with pure CSS:

```css
.Inhalt_lightbox {
 position: fixed;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
 opacity:0;
 -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
 pointer-events: none
}
.Inhalt_lightbox:target {
 opacity:1;
 pointer-events: auto;
}
.Inhalt_lightbox > div {
 width: 400px;
 position: relative;
 margin: 10% auto;
 padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
 background: #fff
}
.close {
 background: #606061;
 color: #FFFFFF;
 line-height: 25px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
 text-align: center;
 top: 0px;
 width: 24px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-weight: bold
}

.close:hover { background: #00d9ff }
```

```html
<div class="item_1">
<div class="Logo"></div>
<div class="Name"></div>
<div class="Link"><a href="#openModal">Open Modal</a></div>
<div class="Inhalt_lightbox" id="openModal"><div><a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
  <h2>Modal Box</h2>
  <p>This is a sample modal box that can be created using the powers of CSS3.</p>
  <p>You could do a lot of things here like have a pop-up ad that shows when your website loads, or create a login/register form for users.</p>
 </div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks But it needs to support IE7 and 8.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest 3 solutions. First:

First - `$('.Inhalt_lightbox').colorbox();`

Second way of implementing that is to add `Inhalt_lightbox` style `visible:hidden` by default and trigger JavaScript function onclick to add style so it could became visible.

Another way is to style active tab using CSS and JS. Here is a similar code snippet as an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#tabs li[id^="li_tab"]').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    var id = this.id.replace('li_', '');
    $('#' + id).show().siblings('div[id^=tab]').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#tabs ul li.active a {
  color: black
}
#tabs ul li.active {
  background-color: white;
}
body {
  height: 600px
}
h1 {
  color: #CC0000;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 18px
}
a.examples {
  color: #CCCCCC
}
a.examples:hover {
  color: black
}
#tabs ul {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#tabs ul li {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 9999;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  -moz-border-top-left: 4px;
  border-top-left: 4px;
  -moz-border-top-right: 4px;
  border-top-right-: 4px;
  width: 130px;
  background-color: #484848;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  clear: none;
  float: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#tabs ul li:hover {
  background-color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-family: verdana;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  border-bottom: white 1px solid;
  height: 60px
}
#tabs #Content_Area {
  padding: 0 15px;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 19px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 5;
  font-size: 11px;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="popupWindows">
  <div id="header">
    <h1>Title</h1>

  </div>
  <div id="tabs" style="height:120px">
    <div style="border-bottom:1px solid #cccccc; height:81px;">
      <ul>
        <li id="li_tab1">
          <a class="examples">1</a>

        </li>
        <li id="li_tab2">
          <a class="examples">2</a>

        </li>
        <li id="li_tab2"> <a class="examples">3</a> 
        </li>
        <li id="li_tab2"> <a class="examples">4</a</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
        </div>
<div id="Content_Area">
        <div id="tab1">
            content
        </div>

        <div id="tab2" class="hidden">
            content
        </div>
        <div id="tab3" class="hidden">
            content
        </div>

        <div id="tab4" class="hidden">
            content         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanky a lot but i want to use the colorbox function of jquery, so that the lightbox looks always the same.

Comment: Yes but im not sure how to call the colorbox event, that the right content shows up.

Comment: I created a fiddle, but i dont know how to call the content: http://jsfiddle.net/Lgdez0dn/